# <%=request.getContextPath()%> equivalent in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 , Java 8, maven

I have this property defined in my `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-path=iberiaWebUtils
```

I would like to know if in my Thymeleaf template there is something equivalent to

```
<a href="/<%=request.getContextPath()%>/iberiaReport/download">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `server.servlet.context-path` with

```
${#httpServletRequest.getContextPath()}
```

And you can just write

```
<a href="@{/iberiaReport/download}">
```

Comment: Just a minor correction: It would be: `<a th:href="@{/iberiaReport/download}">`, using `th:href` instead of simply `href`